# How to download photo from Facebook SDK with Swift 3?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, swift3

Get a crash when downloading user profile photo in iOS app:

```
let dataPhoto = try! Data(contentsOf: photoURL, options: .mappedIfSafe)

(lldb) po photoURL
▿ https:/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/13418946_10208553701714177_3969269576626117653_n.jpg%3Foh=add39246ec9693ecead0529ecbbbfc53&oe=5862D7ED -- file:///

fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “13418946_10208553701714177_3969269576626117653_n.jpg?oh=add39246ec9693ecead0529ecbbbfc53&oe=5862D7ED” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/https:/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/13418946_10208553701714177_3969269576626117653_n.jpg?oh=add39246ec9693ecead0529ecbbbfc53&oe=5862D7ED, NSUnderlyingError=0x170246000 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.46.2/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 178
2016-10-04 12:48:14.317003 Movie Buffs[2722:1318691] fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “13418946_10208553701714177_3969269576626117653_n.jpg?oh=add39246ec9693ecead0529ecbbbfc53&oe=5862D7ED” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/https:/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/13418946_10208553701714177_3969269576626117653_n.jpg?oh=add39246ec9693ecead0529ecbbbfc53&oe=5862D7ED, NSUnderlyingError=0x170246000 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.46.2/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 178
```

What is going on? With earlier Swift it worked.

Got the same result with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift) approach:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: photoURL) {(dataPhoto, response, error) in
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: profilePictureURLStr)
```

need **URL** build like this:

```
let photoURL = URL(string: profilePictureURLStr)!
```